# HTML/CSS Side dropdown on hover displays nothing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a side dropdown menu on hover, but nothing I tried thus far had any effect apart from shortening the containing div to just text.length. What am I doing wrong? Besides, I want to use as little scripting as possible, possibly only HTML and CSS.

Here comes the code...

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Thyra Kristin Lang</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
font-size: xxx-large; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline; }

h4 {
font-size: large; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline; background-color: cyan;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  <!-- width: 20%;    -->
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00000;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 1 em 2 em;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

 /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
}

.menu {
background-color: #a0a0a0; width: 20%; height: 100%; float:left; overflow:hidden;
}

#main {
background-color: #00a000; width: 80%; height: 100%; float:left; overflow:hidden; border: none;
}


#elf {

background-color: #0000c0;
color: #a0a0a0;
font-weight: bold;
}

#elf:hover {

background-color: #0000e0;
color: #c0c0c0;
font-weight: bold;

}

#divine {

background-color: #a000a0;
color: #c0c000;
font-weight: bold;
width;100%;
min-width: 100%
}


#divine:hover {

background-color: #c000c0;
color: #f0f000;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
}





/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}



/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.divine-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.divine:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.divine:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}



.divine-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000f0;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}


.divine-content + a {
  color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline; important!;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
#divine-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
#divine:hover .divine-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
#divine:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}




</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thyra Kristin Lang<br></h1>
<!-- <div width="20%">
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>
  <a href="vita.html" target="main">Lebenslauf</a>
  <a href="werke.html" target="main">Werkeverzeichnis</a>
  <a href="#" name="divine" id="divine">Divine</a>
  <a href="#" name="elf" id="elf">Elfenblut</a>
  <a href="#" name="poetry" id="poetry">Gedichte</a>
  <br>
</div>  -->

<!-- <h2>Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p> -->
<!-- <span id="MyButton" style="font-size:medium; cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">Hauptmenü öffnen</span>  -->


  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- </div>    -->

<div id="wrapper">

<div class="menu" background-color="005000">

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

     <h4>Hauptmenü</h4>
     <div><a href="vita.html" target="main">Lebenslauf</a></div>
     <div><a href="werke.html" target="main">Werkeverzeichnis</a></div>
     <div class="dropdown"><a href="#" name="divine" id="divine">Divine</a>
           <div class="divine-content">
         <a href="#">Link 1</a>
         <a href="#">Link 2</a>
         <a href="#">Link 3</a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#" name="elf" id="elf">Elfenblut</a>
     <a href="#" name="poetry" id="poetry">Gedichte</a>
     <br>
  </div>

</div>

<iframe id="main" name="main" src="willkommen.html" background-color="005000">blub</iframe>



</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow, I wrote some code that seems to answer your question. Essentially what you're aiming to do is display a container on hover of a separate container. Try using the `:hover` event and the adjacent selector via css, this snippet achieves what you are looking for:

**CSS**

```
[name="divine"]:hover + .divine-content {
  display: block;
}
```

notice the :hover event is being placed on your dropdown element and the + sign selector is used because the container you are attempting to show is adjacent to the element you are hovering over.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/arlcode/pen/GRWKBNZ)